# A hyperlink - click on the cell in one sheet to go to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

My question may be trivial, but I search for that in many examples and didn't found something what will be working in my case.

I have one sheet (wsProjects) where I want to have cells with hyperlinks to go to other sheets.
For example: I am in wsProjects sheet, I click on cell named RESOURCES and it takes me to a wsResources sheet.

This is my code:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsResources = Sheets("Resources")
Set wsProjects = Sheets("Projects")
Set wsResourcesProjects = Sheets("ResourcesProjects")

wb.Activate
wsProjects.Activate

iProjectsProjectColumn = 2
iProjectsProjectFirstRow = 8

iProjectsProjectLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, iProjectsProjectColumn).End(xlUp).Row ' --- set last row
Set rProjectsEmptyProjectCell = Cells(iProjectsProjectLastRow + 1, iProjectsProjectColumn)  ' --- set first empty cell

        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).Font.Bold = False
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).Font.Color = RGB(73, 69, 41)
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).Font.Name = "Calibri"
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).Font.Size = 11
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "RESOURCES"
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0).Rows.RowHeight = 20
        wsProjects.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0), Address:=wsResources
```

Error: Type Mismatch

I don't understand what should be set as anchor and what as address. I tried many versions founded in net, but nothing worked.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you specify address for hyperlink if it should redirect to the place in the same workbook:

```
wsProjects.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0), Address:=wsResources
```

First of all, parameter `Address` is of String type and you cannot pass object of `Worksheet` type.

Additionally, if you want a hyperlink to direct to the place in the same worksheet you need to leave property `Address` empty and specify property `SubAddress` instead.

---

Here is how you should modify this line:

```
wsProjects.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rProjectsEmptyProjectCell.Offset(2, 0), _
                            Address:="", SubAddress:=wsResources.Name & "!A1"
```

I assumed that you want to redirect to cell `A1`. If you want to use another cell instead, just change `"!A1"` to whatever cell you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is clear and work correctly.